# Column '' does not belong to table " even though it is present in the table and the query 

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net

Error Message is :

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>   Friendly Message : System.ArgumentException: Column 'testfile' does
>   not belong to table . at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String
>   columnName) at System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName) at
>   Registration_test.FillImage() in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\testWeb\Events\Registration.aspx.cs:line 49 at
>   Registration_test.Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\testWeb\test\Registration.aspx.cs:line 39 at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   Target Site : Boolean HandleError(System.Exception) Source :System.Web
>   Error Stack Trace is : at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at
>   ASP.events_registration_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\testWeb\761ce6e4\d915dd85\App_Web_posk8hm6.6.cs:line 0 at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I have got the above error as email when the site is hosted in IIS, but i donot get it when i am checking the code locally or even online.The error says the testfile column doesnot belong to datable even though the query returns the column.

can anyone help what could be the cause..

//////////////////////this is my code///////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public partial class Registration_Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       FillImage();
    }
    protected void FillImage()
    {

       string Query = "select t.header_image_file as  'HeaderImage',t.image,c.testfile from registrars c left join trade t on c.tradeid =  t.tradeid and c.mainitemid = t.mainitemid ";


       DataTable result = GetDataTable(Query);

       if (result != null && result .Rows.Count > 0)
       {
          if (result .Rows[0]["testfile"] != null)
          {
             this.Theme = result .Rows[0]["testfile"].ToString().Trim();
             this.MasterPageFile = result .Rows[0]["testfile"].ToString().ToLower().Trim() + ".master";
          }
       }
   }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
    }
 }}
```

Comment: what was you tring to do in your code?Registration.aspx.cs:line 49  just check that an please update your answer

Comment: I'm the downvote : you copy /paste an error message from your system without even reading it :"Column 'testfile' does not belong to table" -> you didn't create your column in your production database ! and be more explicit in your title.

Comment: remi bourgarel hope you like my new title.

Comment: can you give use the content of GetDataTable ?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I have a similar situation. Things were working fine until yesterday when these error started coming. As far as I know, there was no change made. And I know it is very random because many users able able to access the page whereas for some the page errors out.
I first thought it is just during the high load, but I can see the errors even on a low load time. Let me know if you found anything useful on it. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I got the problem in our case. It seems all connection pools are getting used up. I reduced the max pool size and ran a load on stage server and could replicate this issue. This post helped me determine about this problem - http://www.ksvali.com/2010/08/solution-to-random-error-column-does-not-belong-to-table/

Answer (score 1):

Ok so at a first glance we are seeing that the error is related to a column not being in a table.

To fix this I suggest you first run the query in management studio, check the names of the columns returned against the ones you are trying to access in your ASP.Net page.
If the column names are all correct backup the data then drop and recreate the table and the stored procedure that accesses this table and hopefully this will solve the issue.

It is a fairly easy to accidentally update a column etc in your database whilst developing and not push that change through to your production database.

If this doesnt solve things you will be able to get better help if you post your table structure, the query and the code which is accessing the query so we can diagnose the problem more efficiently.

UPDATE:
These are the columns you are selecting in your query

```
strt.header_image_file as  'HeaderImage',
t.image,
c.themefile
```

Yet in your code you are trying to access a column called testfile

Comment: i have run the query in the management studio against the database, and the column exists in the table, this error i am not getting always this error is occuring intermittently.

Comment: @PakaujiPakau I updated my answer with what I think is causing the problem. let me know if it's not correct. Thanks

Comment: actually it was a typo mistake while editing i have updated the post the column is testfile